# Why do these two schemes intersect properly?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, intersection-theory, algebraic-cycles

I am studying the [lectures on Motivic cohomology](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjdtJPK8KqBAxVHX_EDHUaFCAEQFnoECCQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.claymath.org%2Flibrary%2Fmonographs%2Fcmim02.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2MdXGFGg-wNk8qUVzE5_Jb&opi=89978449) and I have a problem in the proof of Lemma 1.7.

The lemma says the following: Let $V\subset X\times Y$ and $W\subset Y\times Z$ be irreducible closed subsets which are finite and surjective over $X$ and $Y$ respectively ($X,Y,Z$ are smooth over a field $k$). Then $V\times Z$ and $X\times W$ intersect properly.

The definition of proper intersection given above the lemma is the following:

**Definition:** Two irreducible closed subsets $Z_{1},Z_{2}$ of a smooth scheme are said to intersect **properly** if $Z_{1}\cap Z_{2}=\emptyset$ or $\operatorname{codim}(Z_{1}\cap Z_{2})=\operatorname{codim}(Z_{1})+\operatorname{codim}(Z_{2})$

The lemma starts as follows. We consider the associated integral subschemes of $V$ and $W$ which are noted as $\tilde{V}$ and $\tilde{W}$ respectively. Then we assume without loss of generality that $X,Y$ are connected schemes (since in any case we would give a proof for connected components), so this means $X,Y$ are smooth and connected over a field, hence irreducible.

Next, we consider the fiber product $\tilde{V}\times_{Y}\tilde{W}$ and we prove by another lemma that it is finite and surjective over $\tilde{V}$ and therefore over $X$ too (I can understand why this argument is true). Then we argue that the induced map

$$\tilde{V}\times_{Y}\tilde{W}\to X\times Y\times Z$$ has image $T=\tilde{V}\times Z\cap X\times\tilde{W}$. Then we have that each irreducible component $T_{i}$ of $T$ is the image of an irreducible component of $\tilde{V}\times_{Y}\tilde{W}$ (I should understand it clearly but I think it is not my problem).

The last argument is that $T_{i}$ is finite and surjective over $X$, finite implies integral and by this [Lemma](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ECG) the dimensions $\dim T_{i}=\dim X$ for all $i$ are the same. He then concludes that the closed subschemes $\tilde{V}\times Z$ and $X\times\tilde{W}$ intersect properly.

Namely, I cannot understand the (last) argument given for proving that the closed subschemes $\tilde{V}\times Z$ and $X\times\tilde{W}$ intersect properly. It might be a problem that the definition of proper intersection is given by codimensions (it is given in the lecture notes above the lemma). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Right now your post cannot be answered without clicking on the link and doing a bunch of scrolling, which makes it less likely for you to get an answer (and if the link ever changes, it will become much harder for future readers to understand what's going on here too). Please make your question self-contained by adding the relevant material to your post with an [edit].

Comment: I will try my best, the lecture notes are a standard reference though.

Comment: @KReiser please have a look at my edited answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key fact: if $f\colon A\to B$ is finite and surjective, then $\dim A=\dim B$.

We know that $\tilde{W}$ is finite and surjective over $X$. So $\dim \tilde{W}=\dim X$. This implies $\operatorname{codim} \tilde{W}\times Z = \dim X+\dim Y+\dim Z -(\dim \tilde{W}+\dim Z)=\dim X+\dim Y-\dim X = \dim Y.$

Similarly $\operatorname{codim} X\times \tilde{W} = \dim Z$. So we need to show that $\operatorname{codim} (X\times \tilde{W})\cap (\tilde{W}\times Z)=\dim Y+\dim Z.$

But each $T_i$ is finite and surjective over $X$ and so $\dim X=\dim T_i$. This implies $\operatorname{codim} T_i=\dim Y+\dim Z.$